# MockJAX not responding to CasperJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, casperjs, mockjax

Below is my code which uses casperjs and mockjax . However , mockjax is not able to intercept the ajax call . It returns the ajax response instead of the mock response . 
Also, $.mockjax.mockedAjaxCalls().length this does not print anything . Any idea what I am doing here?

Is there any way I could actually print the value of $.mockjax.mockedAjaxCalls() other than outside evaluate context ??. Please note that mock4.png does show a screenshot indicating that the mockjax callback has not happened .

```
var casper = require("casper").create({
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: 'error',
    clientScripts: ["jquery.mockjax.js", "jquery.js", "json2.js"]
});

casper.on('remote.message', function(msg) {
    this.echo('remote message caught: ' + msg);
})

casper.start('http://xyz:9000/abc', function() {
    this.evaluate(function() {
        this.capture('1.png')
        $.mockjax({
            url: '/foo1',
            responseTime: 100,
            dataType: 'json',
            responseText: {
                sessionTimeoutRedirectUrl: "https://foo/hello",
                errorCode: "error.session.timeout"
            }
        });
    });
    this.capture('xyz123.png');
});


casper.waitForSelector('#order-wrapper', function() {
    this.click('#method-field-cc');
    this.capture('mock2.png');
});
casper.waitForSelector('#cc-card-number', function() {

    this.capture('mock.png');
    this.fillSelectors('form[id="cc-form"]', {
        'input[id="cc-card-number"]': '4112344112344113',
        'input[id="cc-first-name"]': 'first',
        'input[id="cc-last-name"]': 'last',
        'select[id="cc-expiry-month"]': '10',
        'select[id="cc-expiry-year"]': '2016',
        'input[id="tax-field-postal-code"]': '95051',
        'input[id="cc-security-code"]': '123'
    }, true);
    this.click('#review-newcc');
    this.capture('mock3.png');

});

casper.wait(1000, function() {
    this.echo("I've waited for a second.");
    casper.evaluate(function() {
        this.echo("I've waited for a second." + $.mockjax.mockedAjaxCalls().length)
        console.log($.mockjax.mockedAjaxCalls());
    });


});
casper.evaluate(function() {
    this.echo("I've waited for a second." + $.mockjax.mockedAjaxCalls().length)
});
casper.wait(1000, function() {
    this.capture('mock4.png')

});

casper.run();
```

Comment: I don't see where you are trying to hit the URL: `/foo1`. Mockjax only mocks requests that it matches to a URL (and other ajax settings).

Answer (score 0):

Inside of the `casper.evaluate` callback is the page context. The `casper` instance or any other variable from outside is not available there. So, `this` inside of it refers not to the `casper` instance, but to the `window` instance of the page. It's unlikely that it has a `capture` or an `echo` function. Move those call out of the `evaluate` callback to the casper context. Before you do that, register to the `page.error` event and see that those produce errors.

The other problem is that you're adding mockjax before you add jQuery. Since mockjax is a jQuery plugin, you should at least flip the order in `clientScripts`. It might be better to remove `jquery.js` completely, because it will overwrite the one in the page.

Comment: $.mockjax.mockedAjaxCalls() is not available outside casper.evaluate context . Putting this outside of evaluate context produces error running this script . Is there any way I could actually print the value of $.mockjax.mockedAjaxCalls().

Comment: I haven't said that this line should be outside of `evaluate`. I said that the other line beginning with `this` should be moved outside. What you do, should print the value since you registered to the `remote.message` event.

Comment: Have you followed all of my advice? I really don't like giving answers only to find that the OP ignores them. Add the `page.error` event handler and see what errors there are.

Comment: I cannot put in the ajax here since it is sensitive . I captured page.errors and I do not see any errors. I also wanted to highlight that if I try to inject this mockjax on chrome and try to execute the same flow , it works . Also , below is the test run  
remote message caught: No key specified for filter in:eq helper 
remote message caught: MOCK POST: /foo1 [object Object]
remote message caught: Number of mocked ajax response calls : 1


But then , this does not print the response . Does it mean that the mockjax is actually forwarding the call to $.ajax ?

Comment: I see this in my console run :Also , why does it print ? MOCK POST: /foo1 [object Object]

Comment: $.ajax({
                async: false,
                url: '/foo1',
                success:function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error:function(data){
                    console.log('It doesn’t work that way :');
                }
            });

Answer (score 0):

Mockjax will overwrite the jQuery's interface to capture the ajax call, and return with the pre-defined response. You need to place the mockjax after jQuery.js
clientScripts: ["jquery.js", "json2.js", "jquery.mockjax.js"]

Another more stable and generic solution is JSMockServer. https://github.com/gaisanshi/JSMockServer